# How to fill NANs "ignoring" the index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have two dataframes like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': list('abdcde'),
        'B': ['s', np.nan, 'h', 'j', np.nan, 'g']
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'mapcol': list('abpppozl')
    }
)

   A    B
0  a    s
1  b  NaN
2  d    h
3  c    j
4  d  NaN
5  e    g

  mapcol
0      a
1      b
2      p
3      p
4      p
5      o
6      z
7      l
```

I would now like to fill `B` in `df1` using the values of `df2['mapcol']`, however not using the actual index but - in this case - just the first two entries of `df2['mapcol']`. So, instead of `b` and `p` that correspond to index `1` and `4`, respectively, I would like to use the values `a` and `b`.

One way of doing it would be to construct a dictionary with the correct indices and values:

```
df1['B_filled_incorrect'] = df1['B'].fillna(df2['mapcol'])

ind = df1[df1['B'].isna()].index

# reset_index is required as we might have a non-numerical index
val = df2.reset_index().loc[:len(ind-1), 'mapcol'].values

map_dict = dict(zip(ind, val))

df1['B_filled_correct'] = df1['B'].fillna(map_dict)

   A    B B_filled_incorrect B_filled_correct
0  a    s                  s                s
1  b  NaN                  b                a
2  d    h                  h                h
3  c    j                  j                j
4  d  NaN                  p                b
5  e    g                  g                g
```

which gives the desired output.

Is there a more straightforward way that avoids the creation of all these intermediate variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

position fill you can assign the value via the `loc` and convert fill value to `list`

```
df1.loc[df1.B.isna(),'B']=df2.mapcol.iloc[:df1.B.isna().sum()].tolist()
df1
Out[232]: 
   A  B
0  a  s
1  b  a
2  d  h
3  c  j
4  d  b
5  e  g
```

Comment: @YOBEN_S Nice... I going down a rabbit hole of cumsum.. reindex... reset_index.. etc... etc.. etc.. +1

Comment: Mmmh, not part of the original question, but not sure whether it is worth a new one: If there are more `NaNs` in `df1` than `df2` can fill, it will fail. Do you see an easy way to take this into consideration?

Comment: @Cleb `df3=df2.reindex(range(df1.B.isna().sum()))` :-) then 
`df1.loc[df1.B.isna(),'B']=df3.mapcol.tolist()`

Comment: @YOBEN_S: That seems fine; I had a rather ugly `df1.loc[np.where(df1['B'].isna())[0][:df2.mapcol.shape[0]], 'B']`... ;) I'll play a bit more and then accept in a bit.